# get element by ID from php array

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm confused on how to write this correctly
so the ID is distinquished by numbers. example in html:

```
id ="detail_$row["id"]"
```

this is what i'm trying to get in my script

```
document.getElementById("detail_<?php echo $row["id"] ?>").style.visibility = "visible";
```

Comment: use single quote instead double quote like, **"detail_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"**

Answer (score 0):

if you just trying to hide element by id you can use onclick

```
<button onclick="this.style.display = 'none'">Hide Me</button>
```

or you can pass the id to javascript function

```
    <button id="detail_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" onclick="hideElement(this.id)">Hide Me</button>
    <script>
    function hideElement(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: it supposed to work like modal images, so when i click the parent element, this child element shows up, and while it is in a loop, i need to find a way to input the array into javascript getElementById. I have also tried using php echo and json_encode in myscript but doesn't work still..